# Dynamically creating mongo query object

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have a mongo query that I want to run dynamically from within my javascript code

I want to create the query dynamically by providing both the entity and entity id to the query

Given that I have following mappings

```
var EntityMapping = { 
    order: "orderState",
        client: "client",
        clientRelationship: "clientRelationship"
};

var EntityIdMapping = { 
    order: "orderId",
        client: "ctnId",
        clientRelationship: "crIdentification"
};
```

So when I pass values for entity (order, client or clientRelationship) I should get a hierarchy from EntityMapping and EntityIdMapping which I can then use in the query

```
var query = {};
query[entity.EntityMapping].[entity.EntityField] = 45;      // THATS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS. NEED A VALID SYNTAX FOR THIS
mongo_collection.find(query, function(err, c) {});
```

Comment: Can you show us your db structure, so that it will be easier to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a nested object *query* with dynamic keys *a* and *b*. Unless you first initialize the first level child object, you will get an error saying that *query[a]* is undefined and has no property called *b*.

```
var query = {};
query[a] = {}; // Initialize top-level child object
query[a][b] = 45;
```

Using ES6, this would be simpler (http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames):

```
var query = {
  [a]: {
    [b]: 45
  }
}
```